# determining the significance of change

Tags: r, statistical-significance, spatial, spatio-temporal

I have contaminant data in the same area from two surveys conducted 20 years apart (see attached figure). The first survey contain 32 points and second one 48 points. Most of the sampled locations from 1990 didn't exist in 2010. Therefore, I divided them into 4 blocks and determined the average and variance by block kriging using the ‘gstat' package of R. Because there is autocorrelation, we just cannot take the average. My question: how to determine whether or not changes were significant over time in the 4 blocks. The results:

```
block   mean1990    mean2010    var1990 var2010 change  
1       50          70          800     600     -20
2       20          10          670     450     10
3       110         160         500     600     -50
4       76          70          600     490     6
```

Let’s consider just one block (block#01). There’s different schools of thoughts and I’m not sure which one to follow:

(1) If I take the square root of variance, I get standard error: 28 and 25 for 1990 and 2010, respectively; the 95% ($2\sigma$) confidence intervals are [-6, 106] for 1990 and [20, 120] for 2010. Since these intervals overlap - we can reach a conclusion that the change (-20) was not significant.

(2) determining the z-score: 
$\frac{change}{\sqrt(var1990+var2010)}$; which gives $\frac{-20}{37.42} = -0.53$; which is within the 95% confidence limit of [-1.96,1.96]; therefore no change took place.

(3) [others](http://www.lirmm.fr/~strauss/Publications/PaoliTisseyreStrauss03.pdf) say the variance that you get from kriging has no relationship with data, therefore, the confidence intervals should be determined by bootstrapping, etc.

Can anyone kindly shed some light on this?[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could use regression-kriging to model the effect of sampling period on the observed variable?